# Bootstrap tooltip showing behind modal window

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a modal window which consists this `div`:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon" title="Insert here your domain account name" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="Account">
        @Html.Label("Domain account name", new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Login, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login)
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is a tooltip on the label.

It's initalized with this code:

```
$('#Account').tooltip({ container: 'body' });
```

The code is working, but the tooltip is showing behind the modal. I tried setting the `z-index` of the tooltip like this:

```
.tooltip {
    z-index: 1151,!important;
}
```

or

```
 #Account {
     z-index: 1151,!important;
 }
```

but none of them worked.

Can you suggest how should I set up CSS to make this tooltip show on top of the modal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try without comma before !important:

```
.tooltip{
  z-index: 1151 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do one thing. Check the z-index of your modal popup & set the tooltip z-index +1 of your modal popup z-index.

so it would be like

```
.tooltip{
  z-index:( z-index of modal popup + 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
.tooltip{
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
```