# Bootstrap Tooltip showing behind modal MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am unable to get my Bootstrap Tooltips to show properly inside my Modal.

I have a MVC Site where i sometimes load Partial Views with Ajax and show them inside a Modal. When the user Clicks the button, i perform the Get and update the Modal Body with the Html.
My code contains my current test to get the Modal to show properly.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#modal-Levering-body').html(response);

            var button = $('#UdleveringVHButton');
            button.attr('value', 'Found the button');
            button.tooltip({ container: '#modal-Levering-body' });
        }
```

My Button is defined in my View as

```
        <input type="button" id="UdleveringVHButton" value="Udlevering VH" class="btn btn-xs" title="Sæt alle varer til Udlevering Varehus"
           data-tooltip="yes" data-placement="top" />
```

This is the result when i mouse-ver the 'found the button' button 
[image: Tooltip is shown behind the Modal]

The Weird thing is that when i try this on JSFiddle, it works just fine
http://jsfiddle.net/z6qqvycf/

I am limited in my debugging, because i do not know how to inspect the Tooltip. It is not visible from Chrome Development Tools.

I have also looked at [Bootstrap tooltip showing behind modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603255/bootstrap-tooltip-showing-behind-modal-window) but this did not affect my situation.

Any suggestions on how to debug and fix this situation?

**EDIT:**

Found this guide on how to Inspect the Tooltip:

[Freeze screen in chrome debugger / DevTools panel for popover inspection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931571/freeze-screen-in-chrome-debugger-devtools-panel-for-popover-inspection)

**EDIT2:**

I found that my Tooltip is entirely different than my JSFiddler
JSFiddler
[image: Html from JSFiddler example]

My MVC Setup
[image: Html from MVC]

Somehow the .tooltip function is generating something entirely different on my setup than in my JSFiddler. Unknown why currently.

**EDIT 3**

Found out that there is a conflict between Bootstrap and JQUery UI on the .tooltip() function.
I was loading JQuery UI last so it won.

I reversed the loading order and now it all works as expected
[jQueryUI Tooltips are competing with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731400/jqueryui-tooltips-are-competing-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: check z-index of that div

Comment: How do i check Z-index of that div? It is not available in the Chrome Developer pane.
When i remove my mouse from the button's mouseover the tooltip dissapears

Comment: try looking into `bootstrap.css` on `.tooltip` style

Comment: Try adding data-container="body" (e.g. html body element) or whatever the id is on your dialog.  I guess data-container="modal-Levering-body".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there is a conflict between Bootstrap and JQUery UI on the .tooltip() function. I was loading JQuery UI last, so it took precedence.

I reversed the loading order and loaded the Bootstrap JS file last and now it all works as expected.